# Should a header background picture be included in the bundle or loaded through a cdn?

Tags: reactjs, performance, cdn

The question says it all: in term of performance, should a large header background picture for the homepage be included in the bundle or loaded through a cdn? I'm using React + webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Load times should be the same if your bundle and the image are behind the same CDN.

If you don't have the bundle behind a CDN then the CDN will probably be faster.

Using a modern format, image compression, using the right resolution and transfer compression can more of a difference than the source it's served from  - so make you have those right first